# Javascript array won't update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I'm making an RPS Bot (rock, paper, scissors robot) in Javascript.
Everything works perfectly, except when I tried to add a section to the code that displays the user's scores if they type "scores" or "all scores" into the input box.
I've looked over my code for errors, and even tried to use http://jsfiddle.net/ to debug it, but it tells me that there are no errors.

So here's the main game Javascript, the problem is most likely starting from here:

```
var play = function() {
    var randomINT = function(min, max) {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
        if (random > max || random < min) {
            random = "ERROR";
        }
        return random;
    };

    var capitalize = function(input) {
        return input.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1);
    };

    var reset = function() {
        document.getElementById('input').value = "";
        document.getElementById('result').scrollTop = document.getElementById(
            'result').scrollHeight;
    };

    var getInput = document.getElementById('input').value.toLowerCase();
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var getRandom = randomINT(1, 4);
    var output = ["", "", "", "", "", ""];

    var scores = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    /*^This^ is the scores array, scores[0] is the number of times the user has won, scores[1] is the number of times the user has lost, scores[2] is the number of draws for the user, scores[3] is the number of times the computer has won, scores[4] is the number of times the computer has lost, scores[5] is the number of draws for the computer*/
    if (getInput === "" || getInput === null) {
        getInput = "_Blank";
    }

    if (username === "" || username === null) {
        username = "user";
    }

    if (getInput.substring(0, 5) == "clear" || getInput == "cls") {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "";
        reset();
        return;
    } else if (getInput.substring(0, 2) == "my" || getInput.substring(0, 4) ==
        "user") {
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("SPAN")
            .appendChild(document.createTextNode(
                "Your total scores:")));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("SPAN")
            .appendChild(document.createTextNode(
                "Wins: " + scores[0])));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("SPAN")
            .appendChild(document.createTextNode(
                "Losses: " + scores[1])));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("SPAN")
            .appendChild(document.createTextNode(
                "Draws: " + scores[2])));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
        reset();
        return;
    } else if (getInput.substring(0, 4) == "comp") {
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("SPAN")
            .appendChild(document.createTextNode(
                "Computer's total scores:")));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("SPAN")
            .appendChild(document.createTextNode(
                "Wins: " + scores[3])));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("SPAN")
            .appendChild(document.createTextNode(
                "Losses: " + scores[4])));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("SPAN")
            .appendChild(document.createTextNode(
                "Draws: " + scores[5])));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
        reset();
        return;
    } else if (getInput.substring(0, 3) == "all" || getInput.substring(0, 6) ==
        "scores") {
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("SPAN")
            .appendChild(document.createTextNode(
                "All total scores:")));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("SPAN")
            .appendChild(document.createTextNode(
                "Your wins: " + scores[0])));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("SPAN")
            .appendChild(document.createTextNode(
                "Your losses: " + scores[1])));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("SPAN")
            .appendChild(document.createTextNode(
                "Your draws: " + scores[2])));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("SPAN")
            .appendChild(document.createTextNode(
                "Computer's wins: " + scores[3])));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("SPAN")
            .appendChild(document.createTextNode(
                "Computer's losses: " + scores[4])));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("SPAN")
            .appendChild(document.createTextNode(
                "Computer's draws: " + scores[5])));
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
        reset();
        return;
    }

    //Main game logic section
    if (getRandom == 1) {
        //If computer picked rock
        if (getInput == "rock") {
            output[5] = "YES";
            output[0] = capitalize(username) + " picked: Rock";
            output[1] = "Computer picked: Rock";
            output[2] = "*CLUNK SOUND*: Rocks smash against each other";
            output[3] = "DRAW";
            scores[2] = scores[2] + 1;
            scores[5] = scores[5] + 1;
        } else if (getInput == "paper") {
            output[5] = "YES";
            output[0] = capitalize(username) + " picked: Paper";
            output[1] = "Computer picked: Rock";
            output[2] = "Paper beats Rock";
            output[3] = capitalize(username) + " Wins";
            scores[0] = scores[0] + 1;
            scores[4] = scores[4] + 1;
        } else if (getInput == "scissors") {
            output[5] = "YES";
            output[0] = capitalize(username) + " picked: Scissors";
            output[1] = "Computer picked: Rock";
            output[2] = "Rock beats Scissors";
            output[3] = "Computer Wins";
            scores[1] = scores[1] + 1;
            scores[3] = scores[3] + 1;
        } else {
            output[5] = "NO";
            output[4] = 'ERROR: Computer does not understand what "' + getInput +
                '" is.';
        }
    } else if (getRandom == 2) {
        //If computer picked paper
        if (getInput == "rock") {
            output[5] = "YES";
            output[0] = capitalize(username) + " picked: Rock";
            output[1] = "Computer picked: Paper";
            output[2] = "Paper beats Rock";
            output[3] = "Computer Wins";
            scores[1] = scores[1] + 1;
            scores[3] = scores[3] + 1;
        } else if (getInput == "paper") {
            output[5] = "YES";
            output[0] = capitalize(username) + " picked: Paper";
            output[1] = "Computer picked: Paper";
            output[2] = "*SWISH SOUND* Papers brush against each other";
            output[3] = "DRAW";
            scores[2] = scores[2] + 1;
            scores[5] = scores[5] + 1;
        } else if (getInput == "scissors") {
            output[5] = "YES";
            output[0] = capitalize(username) + " picked: Scissors";
            output[1] = "Computer picked: Paper";
            output[2] = "Scissors beats Paper";
            output[3] = capitalize(username) + " Wins";
            scores[0] = scores[0] + 1;
            scores[4] = scores[4] + 1;
        } else {
            output[5] = "NO";
            output[4] = 'ERROR: Computer does not understand what "' + getInput +
                '" is.';
        }
    } else if (getRandom == 3) {
        //If computer picked scissors
        if (getInput == "rock") {
            output[5] = "YES";
            output[0] = capitalize(username) + " picked: Rock";
            output[1] = "Computer picked: Scissors";
            output[2] = "Rock beats Scissors";
            output[3] = capitalize(username) + " Wins";
            scores[0] = scores[0] + 1;
            scores[4] = scores[4] + 1;
        } else if (getInput == "paper") {
            output[5] = "YES";
            output[0] = capitalize(username) + " picked: Paper";
            output[1] = "Computer picked: Scissors";
            output[2] = "Scissors beats Paper";
            output[3] = "Computer Wins";
            scores[1] = scores[1] + 1;
            scores[3] = scores[3] + 1;
        } else if (getInput == "scissors") {
            output[5] = "YES";
            output[0] = capitalize(username) + " picked: Scissors";
            output[1] = "Computer picked: Scissors";
            output[2] = "*CLINK SOUND*: Scissors hit each other";
            output[3] = "DRAW";
            scores[2] = scores[2] + 1;
            scores[5] = scores[5] + 1;
        } else {
            output[5] = "NO";
            output[4] = 'ERROR: Computer does not understand what "' + getInput +
                '" is.';
        }
    } else {
        output[5] = "NO";
        output[4] = "ERROR: Randomizer function seems to be broken";
    }

    var finish = function(input) {
        if (input === undefined) {
            if (output[5] == "YES") {
                document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
                document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement(
                    "SPAN").appendChild(document.createTextNode(
                    output[0])));
                document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
                document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement(
                    "SPAN").appendChild(document.createTextNode(
                    output[1])));
                document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
                document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement(
                    "SPAN").appendChild(document.createTextNode(
                    output[2])));
                document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
                document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement(
                    "SPAN").appendChild(document.createTextNode(
                    output[3])));
                document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
            } else {
                document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
                document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement(
                    "SPAN").appendChild(document.createTextNode(
                    output[4])));
                document.getElementById("result").appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
            }
        }
    };

    finish();
    reset();
};
```

I apologize in advance for the untidy code.

Comment: You might want to look into one of the various JavaScript template engines available. It'd make code like yours **much** cleaner.

Comment: please link to your jsfiddle ... AND ... It is better working with objects

Comment: Your code would be much easier to read and maintain if you used objects instead of arrays, e.g. `scores.wins`, `scores.losses`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the advice everybody, I'm going to put it into action ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `scores` is a local variable in your `play` function, so it gets reinitialized every time the user starts another game. It needs to be a global variable, outside the function, so its value persists from one call to the next.

```
var scores = [0,0,0,0,0,0];
var play = function() {
    ...
}
```

And it would be better to make it an object:

```
var scores = {
    humanWin: 0,
    humanLose: 0,
    draw: 0
};
```

I don't see why you need additional elements for computer wins, losses, and draw; the number of computer wins is always the same as human losses and vice versa, and they both have the same number of draws.

Comment: Wow, so that was the problem...
Right now I feel completely like some blind noob.
Anyway thanks! XD